# Date in c#, mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database connected to c# windows forms application. I want to get a current date and time from database, and then to use that date and time to insert some other data into database.

When I execute a query `select now()` from WAMP's mySqlConsole I get what I expect: `12-04-17 12:06:28`, but when I run that same query from c# and store the value to string like this:  `String datetime = cmdDatetime.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` the month becomes `Apr` in which format i cant insert into db.

Is there a way for c# to store mysql `datetime` in the same format as it is in mysql?

Comment: Try to *avoid* using strings if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime` object if possible, or else you will need to convert the date time received to the format you want:

```
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)cmdDatetime.ExecuteScalar();

string dateTimeString = dateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Using the `InvariantCulture`, you will always get the results in the same way, namely in the `en-US` settings.

Additionally, you can force the specific format too:

```
string dateTimeString = dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @PatricHofman I only have `CultureInfoConverter` as the option for parameters in `ToString`.

Comment: @wdc you'll need to add `using System.Globalization;` probably

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the format for example:

```
DateTime datet = (DateTime)cmdDatetime.ExecuteScalar();
String datetime = datet.ExecuteScalar().ToString( "dd-mm-yyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try That:

```
DateTime datetime = (DateTime)cmdDatetime.ExecuteScalar();
String datetimeStr = datetime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Comment: That doesn't compile.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns an object. You'll need to cast it to `DateTime` before trying to `ToString` with a format